# 8-bit reading on x64 machines

Tags: language-agnostic, cpu

I have read that long values (I believe all date types with 8-bit size) are read by CPU in two steps:
the first step is reading first 32 bits, and the second one is reading next 32 bit.

Is this statement true regarding only 32-bit machines?

Comment: First of all, this question is language-agnostic so I changed the tag. Secondly, this really depends on the CPU and its architecture. Thirdly, with modern mainstream CPU's with multi-megabyte caches and prefetching and all, it's a lot more advanced than that.

Comment: why are you asking?

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov interesting how it works behind the scenes

Comment: Different processors behave differently.